# HTMLDOC Chinese language Support

Tags: php, htmldoc

I have a page with the Chinese content written in it. I am using htmldoc to convert it to PDF. Now while converting to PDF it shows garbage characters and not the Chinese characters. I have my html pages in multiple languages. When users clicks on download as PDF I want to convert them to pdf in those languages. Its working perfectly fine for English but for languages other than English I am facing problem.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This could be a font problem, required font is not getting found by the `HTMLDOC`.. I am just guessing the problem though..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as htmldoc author mentioned at http://michaelrsweet.github.io/htmldoc/:

> you can’t use HTMLDOC to format Arabic, Chinese, Hebrew, Japanese, or other languages that are not based on latin-based alphabets that read left-to-right